# Paypal PDT curl request error

Tags: php, curl, paypal

> Below is the code for my paypal receive file for using paypal PDT

```
<?php

  $tx = $_GET['tx'];
  $ID = $_GET['cm'];
  $amount = $_GET['amt'];
  $currency = $_GET['cc'];
  $auth = "#####";

  // Init cURL
  $ch = curl_init(); 

  // Set request options
  $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
  $fields = array(
      'cmd' => '_notify-synch',
      'tx' => $tx,
      'at' => $auth
  );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cacert.pem');
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

  // Execute request and get response and status code
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $status   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  // Close connection
  curl_close($ch);
  print_r($response);
  if($status == 200 AND strpos($response, 'SUCCESS') === 0)
  {
      //wp_redirect(home_url('/account'));
      exit;
  } else {
     // wp_redirect(home_url());
      exit;
  }
?>
```

> I have tried many times now..but it is still throwing error...i have
>   tested server for curl and its working with other file...can anyone
>   has any idea why this is not working
>
> Whenever i try to print_r th response ..its empty and show nothing

Comment: "it is still throwing error" -> If you don't provide the error, we won't be able to help ?

Comment: What errors is it throwing? Use [curl_errors()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to get more details. FYI it better to use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) instead of plain `curl`. It will save you struggling with debuging.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify that...its showing nothing ...i mean absolutely nothing..even i print_r the response.
On print_r to status its is showing 0

Comment: 0 == `false` - your request was not successful. Check [return values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-returnvalues)

Comment: @LukasHajdu i have print_r the response and its empty ..i mean nothing is printing

Comment: Try to replace your `$response = curl_exec($ch);` with `$response = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_errors());` (as @LukasHajdu suggested) please

Comment: print_r is empty when response is false or empty, can you provide a `var_dump($response)` instead of print_r ?

Comment: @Julqas on var_dump it is showing bool(false) int(0) and on adding die(curl_error()) its showing nothing

Comment: What did you var_dump ? because `bool(false) int(0)` are two results of var_dump, which one is what ? Beside can your provide a `var_dump($status);` please ?

Comment: @Julqas  response :bool(false) and status :int(0) on var_dump

Comment: Do you have something in your PHP logs ? If not the only thoughts I'm left with here is the SSL part. Can you look that thread and see if it helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364427/paypal-pdt-not-working-using-curl?rq=1

Comment: i have included the cecert file also..but it's is still not working..and yes i have checked that thread but ..code is almost same...i could not understand what is the problem

Comment: In that thread they added "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" to false, and "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST" to 2, two things that can explain the problem. Moreover, are you sure your cert file is reachable ? they are using "realpath()" to get the full file path, maybe you should try that as well ?

Comment: @Julqas i have user the realpath now but still not success with it

Comment: Can you test something like `var_dump(file_exists(realpath('cacert.pem')))` please, to be sure it is found or not ?

Comment: @Julqas i have checked var_dump the path as you have specified and i got this output: bool(true)

Comment: Can you add then these two lines like the other post I linked ? `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );` and `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );` ?

Comment: @Julqas ok i was closing   curl_close($ch) before echoing error that's why error was not showing ...now its showing Curl error: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: @Julqas i have put the code that you given ...its still the same

Comment: Can you change `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );` by `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3 );` to test ?

Comment: @Julqas ...same result nothing happened

Comment: and changing `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3 );` to `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 4 );` ?

Comment: @Julqas same..i think the error is coming because paypal has upgraded its certification check to  SHA-256, 2048-bit certificates

Comment: Oh yes I forgot they had to do it on 2016/06/17 (changing to HTTP/1.1, TLS 1.2 and SHA-256 2048bits certificates).
In that case change `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 4 );` to `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 6 );`

Comment: @Julqas same error no change: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: Can you remove `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resume the conversation :

- You have to use realpath() on your cert to be sure it finds it.
- Since 17th June 2016, Paypal upgraded its API. You have to use TLS 1.2 now (CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = 6 for cURL use) (see more here : https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US)

```
  $tx = $_GET['tx'];
  $ID = $_GET['cm'];
  $amount = $_GET['amt'];
  $currency = $_GET['cc'];
  $auth = "#####";

  // Init cURL
  $ch = curl_init(); 

  // Set request options
  $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
  $fields = array(
      'cmd' => '_notify-synch',
      'tx' => $tx,
      'at' => $auth
  );
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 6);   //force TLS 1.2
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath('cacert.pem'));
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

  // Execute request and get response and status code
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $status   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  // Close connection
  curl_close($ch);
  print_r($response);
  if($status == 200 AND strpos($response, 'SUCCESS') === 0)
  {
      //wp_redirect(home_url('/account'));
      exit;
  } else {
     // wp_redirect(home_url());
      exit;
  }
?>
```

Comment: I don't know how but the error is resolved ..i just put the absolute path for the cecert file....now curl response is properly coming...thank you everyone for support. 
sorry for the late message...:)

Comment: I'm glad that it finally worked for you ! Have a good dev with it ! If there is an answer that provide the good correction to make, don't forget to accept it to help the community.